# Applying BODMAS to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a form with questions on it, the user has 3 radio buttons to check, 'pass', 'fail' and 'n/a'. At the bottom I have a function to count the passes and fails and out put the total and percentage. I.e if 8 out of 10 are answered pass and 2 are failed, it will give a score of 8 out of 10 and percent of 80%.

I'm trying to incorporate the n/a and have the following calculation where a question doesn't apply...

pass/(10-n/a)

That will take all the passes and divide it by the total questions minus the n/a's.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    var yes = $('.pass:checked').length
    var no = $('.no:checked').length
    //var na = $('.n/a:checked').length

    var yes=Math.round(yes/114*100);
      //var yes=Math.round(yes/(125-na));
    $('.percent_results').text(yes)
    $('.no_results').text(no)

    $('#totalAuditScore2').val(yes);
})
});
```

As above I've tried a third variable but it stops the function working. How can I get this to function? Thanks.

Comment: as per my understanding from your question this should work - `Math.round((pass/(toal-not_applicable))*100)`

Comment: Not quite, if the total is 10 questions, 8 have answered yes, and 2 are n/a, then the sum would be 8/(10-2), so therefore in the function it would be pass/(10-n/a)

Comment: What error message are you getting? What do you mean by 'stops working'?

Comment: What does any of this have to do with BODMAS? All progamming languages (including JS) apply BODMAS out of the box. Your title doesn't make a lot of sense. What does *"but it stops the function working"* mean? Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @Peter the error i'm getting in the console is: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .n/a:checked" - When I uncomment the 'var na = $('.n/a:checked').length' line. By not working, the span I have at the bottom of the form that live updates the score based on each radio input selection doesn't add up and stays on 0%

Comment: "/" is not an allowed character in a CSS class. Try changing it to "na" or "n-a".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue, thanks to combination of both @Kaushik and @corschdi. I removed the slashes in my n/a's and changed the math to the following...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    var pass = $('.pass:checked').length
    var fail = $('.fail:checked').length
    var na = $('.na:checked').length


      var pass=Math.round(pass/(125-na)*100);

    $('.percent_results').text(pass)
    $('.no_results').text(fail)


    $('#totalAuditScore2').val(pass);
})
});
```